# Vala code with static struct dont works after update to 0.44

Tags: vala

Just did a standard job interview is to calculate the volume of water in the histogram. On Monday this code worked, and [still works](https://tio.run/##rVTLatwwFN3nK27DEKzaM4yTXVxP2w8odJ9koczYicCPwZKHgDG02ZUGCl11118ooYVCmvQX5C@aXkl@Tey2UKqNrq@uzjlXx9KGRnS7XUaUc3gZXaSCiRiggD3AwUWWLwWELOMCCp0yaSrYElgiYEUF9QDGltYp98xC2QfjwTJNVv@GBg2entb5eYSrdVEj3iI97LKNdosVIqfcwvnkDGJsnhR7ba0aYZqBWgbmzz0Gz3TRLAqSC3HpAbNtslOuBgvBUlUn7AwW5tBmqiNSDEo1Q1vg17u8Ooe9gg/MKwf7/ofEjnfhd3KNLToNBwfAnvitlt/o7@3oGqiT4x3sfGjhiQiyDY3AV32QV1RczkJ6zi1rlaJfAbFaEdMOeeoS4g2weB7HyDn3hjQxS15rQVaHt@jwyPMutt3jtsR2R2hievVnrDZ73Mt66ww3Wy/2WykTE532ECcmOk32H/F2RmOV2Yf@asOvTDzmtfYID8Vu3Rn@TsNTVJ3VimBak5GnGsF8TN1HQFygWdix6jDEFuVneScfqnfyi/xa3ai@RlpSXFnA80iAz5FICf0L7Cd5X13Lb9UbeYvQdwq4@X/wFOVH@YB870H@xOAH1r3F6u/VdXWD0QeY1GxDKY01oXrkELR3QYi5kLU9neFE/ec61bsEOtmU9rxXfDuEWSDyLKnb77SU6Ae@bJuUrdBYllj1vTNvFEXYwnWOnLnjOoc4HzpuaTY3L99MvWgU2crt9hc) on this site. After updating vala, an error is now displayed.

UPD: more easy [example](https://pastebin.com/nETwvY9N)

```
> Algoritm.vala:2.5-2.16: error: struct `Algotitm.first' cannot be empty
>     struct first {
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Algoritm.vala:6.5-6.17: error: struct `Algotitm.second' cannot be empty
>     struct second {
```

Comment: Please write the actual code into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting a question on Stack Overflow it is always good to post an example of the code that is a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

From the link you've provided it appears you have a struct with only members marked as `static`:

```
struct First {
    static int data;
    static int pos; 
}

void main () {
}
```

Marking the fields as `static` means they aren't instance fields and so the struct is empty of fields. That's why you are getting the error message about the struct being empty. I'm not sure Vala should even allow marking struct fields as static, but it does make sense to allow methods in structs to be static.

You need to remove the `static` modifiers. This will work:

```
struct First {
    int data;
    int pos;
}

void main () {
}
```

#### Update

I'm guessing you are trying to write performance optimized code and you think `static` helps with that. `static` in Vala means there is no instance data to use. If you are using a data structure like a class or struct then it only makes sense to have instances of those. If you want something to remain unchanged during the running of your program use `const` in a namespace.

Using a struct may give you a slight performance boost if your are using a very large number in your program. structs created in Vala are allocated on the stack instead of the heap so may be slightly faster. If you are passing structs around you may want to consider `[SimpleType]` attribute. That means structs will be passed by value in C as well as Vala. Without the `[SimpleType]` they are copied and passed by reference at the C level, which appears as copy by value in Vala.

Structs in Vala can have initializers (similar to a constructor for a class) and methods. So what I can extract from your second pastebin you could write that as:

```
struct First {
    int data;
    int pos;

    public First (int[] mass) {
        data= 5;
        pos = mass.length;
    }

    public int sas () {
        return data + pos;
    }
}

void main () {
    int[] a = {1,3,0,1,2,3,2,1};
    var b = First (a);
    print (@"$(b.sas ())\n");
}
```

That is a follow on question though and should be asked as a second question on Stack Overflow. This is a public forum that follows a format that allows other people to learn from the question and answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! (I already have another question about Grid.Array and why can't I put int into it ^^)
Ok, i will make another quastion with answear.